# IAM permission 'dialogflow.conversations.list' on 'projects' denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've created a custom role in GCP, which I'm using to assign limited access to our business users, enabling them to train the chatbot.  At the moment they can perform the functions as needed using the Training module, I would also like to give access to the History module, but I keep hitting an error

> IAM permission 'dialogflow.conversations.list' on 'projects' denied.

When I try and add this permission, it's not available.  I've noticed the second I make a copy of a standard dialogflow permission group, this object goes missing.

Any suggestions on how I can enable access to this module?

[Add Permissions Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vuOM.png)

Comment: Hey Paul, were you able to fix this? I'm having a similar issue where I am trying to create a Dialogflow agent through an API call, using a Service Account as auth. But I'm getting permission denied :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles#known_limitations), Not all permissions can be used for custom IAM role.

Custom IAM role has a limitation that some permissions are not available.

Below is description about limitation of custom IAM from google document page.

> Some predefined roles contain permissions that are not permitted in
> custom roles. To check whether you can use a specific permission in a
> custom role, see Support level for permissions in custom roles.

Also, I checked whether *dialogflow.conversations.list* permission is permitted or not. But It didn't even exist.

You can also check it [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/custom-roles-permissions-support#list_of_all_permissions_and_support_levels).

I think you can just grant a [dialogflow.conversationManager](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#dialogflow-roles) role to group or users for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

That dialogflow.conversationManager role looks perfect, I'll switch to that.

Many thanks!